Remove the deeply nested structure from the JSON and simplify it
I have a JSON which has deep nested structure, I want a generic function in Javascript/Typescript to remove that multiple deep structure. Generic like there might me any parent other than categories that may have nesting in its keys.
Here is an example JSON with deep nesting:-
const nestedObject = {
    "code": {
      "prev": [],
      "current": null
    },
    "updatedAt": {
      "prev": "2024-05-22T12:33:38.834Z",
      "current": "2024-05-23T08:47:11.151Z"
    },
    "categories": {
      "5": {
        "prev": null,
        "current": {
          "id": 12,
          "name": "Value-1"
        }
      },
      "6": {
        "prev": null,
        "current": {
          "id": 13,
          "name": "Value-2"
        }
      },
      "7": {
        "prev": null,
        "current": {
          "id": 14,
          "name": "Value-3"
        }
      },
      "25": {
        "24": {
          "23": {
            "22": {
              "21": {
                "20": {
                  "19": {
                    "18": {
                      "prev": null,
                      "current": {
                        "id": 25,
                        "name": "Value-3"
                      }
                    },
                    "prev": null,
                    "current": {
                      "id": 26,
                      "name": "Value-4"
                    }
                  },
                  "prev": null,
                  "current": {
                    "id": 27,
                    "name": "Value-5"
                  }
                },
                "prev": null,
                "current": {
                  "id": 28,
                  "name": "Value-6"
                }
              },
              "prev": null,
              "current": {
                "id": 29,
                "name": "Value-7"
              }
            },
            "prev": null,
            "current": {
              "id": 30,
              "name": "Value-8"
            }
          },
          "prev": null,
          "current": {
            "id": 31,
            "name": "Value-9"
          }
        },
        "prev": null,
        "current": {
          "id": 32,
          "name": "Value-10"
        }
      }
    }
  };

In the example there's deep nesting in the categories (i.e., 25->24->23->22->21...).
I want to make it like categories.3 and categories.4
Following is the Expected Output that I want the generic function to give:-
const expectedOutput = {
    "code": {
      "prev": [],
      "current": null
    },
    "updatedAt": {
      "prev": "2024-05-22T12:33:38.834Z",
      "current": "2024-05-23T08:47:11.151Z"
    },
    "categories": {
      "5": {
        "prev": null,
        "current": {
          "id": 12,
          "name": "Value-1"
        }
      },
      "6": {
        "prev": null,
        "current": {
          "id": 13,
          "name": "Value-2"
        }
      },
      "7": {
        "prev": null,
        "current": {
          "id": 14,
          "name": "Value-3"
        }
      },
      "18": {
        "prev": null,
        "current": {
          "id": 25,
          "name": "Value-3"
        }
      },
      "19": {
        "prev": null,
        "current": {
          "id": 26,
          "name": "Value-4"
        }
      },
      "20": {
        "prev": null,
        "current": {
          "id": 27,
          "name": "Value-5"
        }
      },
      "21": {
        "prev": null,
        "current": {
          "id": 28,
          "name": "Value-6"
        }
      },
      "22": {
        "prev": null,
        "current": {
          "id": 29,
          "name": "Value-7"
        }
      },
      "23": {
        "prev": null,
        "current": {
          "id": 30,
          "name": "Value-8"
        }
      },
      "24": {
        "prev": null,
        "current": {
          "id": 31,
          "name": "Value-9"
        }
      },
      "25": {
        "prev": null,
        "current": {
          "id": 32,
          "name": "Value-10"
        }
      }
    }
  };

I found a function that flattens the JSON. But this doesn't give me the expected output. Here's the function.
const flattenObject = (obj, prefix = '') => {
  let result = {};

  for (let key in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[key] === 'object' && obj[key] !== null && !Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
      const nested = flattenObject(obj[key], `${prefix}${key}.`);
      result = { ...result, ...nested };
    } else {
      result[`${prefix}${key}`] = obj[key];
    }
  }

  return result;
};


Do you understand how flattenObject works? Have you written it yourself?

Are you in a position to fix how the JSON data is created?

@Bergi Yes i do, i was thinking of flattening the whole JSON and then converting it to desired format (i.e., removing the nested keys), but there may be something that is easier

@traktor I'm looking into that too, but for now it'll be really good to have a check for it in the final data too.

Here's the function that accomplishes what you need for the provided JSON:
const flatObj = flattenNestedObject(nestedObject)

function flattenNestedObject({ categories, ...rest }) {
  return { 
    // copy all fields except `categories`
    ...rest,
    // overwrite `categories` with a flattened version
    categories: flattenCategories(categories)
  }
}

function flattenCategories(categories) {
    // iterate category keys
    return Object.keys(categories)
      .reduce((result, key) => {
        // extract all nested categories for the given key
        // and return the new accumulated result
        return flattenCategory(categories[key], result, key)
      }, {})
}

/**
 * 
 * @param category category object to flatten
 * @param result accumulated result, the flattened category is assigned here
 * @param catKey key of the category out of which we're pulling the nested categories
 * @returns accumulated result with all current nested categories flattened
 */
function flattenCategory(category, result, catKey) {
  // iterate category's keys
  return Object.keys(category)
    .reduce((acc, key) => {
      // set `catKey` with some placeholder values on the currently
      // acc. result, if it isn't already set
      acc[catKey] ??= { prev: null, current: { id: -1, name: "" } }
      if (key === "prev" || key === "current") {
        // if key is "prev" or "current", just set its value in the acc. result
        acc[catKey][key] = category[key]
        return acc
      } else {
        // key must be related to a nested category, so extract all nested
        // categories for the given key and return the new acc. result
        return flattenCategory(category[key], acc, key)
      }
    }, result)
}

